# Проблема с большими русскими буквами (MAMP)

Tags: apache, mamp, mac, php

Mac OSX leo. Mamp. При написании больших русских букв в коде меняет их на левые символы ( ‘лезин €горь сказал: "I'll be back"). Пробовал писать внутри html кода, выставлял параметры шрифта, пытался менять кодировку - 0. Помогите.

Answer (score 1):

Всё достаточно просто! Необходимо выставить кодировку файла на UTF-8. 
К примеру в Code это делаеться так:
**Text** -> **Encoding** -> Unicode(UTF-8). А вообще в настройках программы можно выставить создание новых документов с заданной кодировкой, что бы каждый раз не париться (или забывать).